# how "apt-get -f install" recognize problems from "dpkg"?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

While I was installing Discord, some packages were needed - `libgconf-2-4`, `libappindicator1` and `libc++1`.

This is the error message.

```
Selecting previously unselected package discord.
(Reading database ... 281442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack discord-0.0.14.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.14) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
 discord depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package discord (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 discord
```

Internet said to use `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix this, and it worked well.

**But How**?

How `apt-get` recognizes `dpkg`'s dependency problem and fix it?

Is there some problematic-package/dependency-listing file in Linux system I guess?

Can you please explain me how? Thanks.

Comment: It's the magical '-f' (force) flag. See the dpkg manage for an explanation.

Comment: I think that should have read man page

Comment: @David I have searched man of dpkg and apt(-get) before I post. dpkg man mentioned apt but slightly, not like collaboration or functionality with apt

Comment: There is no `discord` package in the Ubuntu repositories. It's unclear what source you are getting that package from.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try to explain this the best I can.  `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` and `dpkg` are all tied together.  `dpkg` is actually the "package manger for Debian", source `man dpkg`.  If you run `dpkg --help` you will see the following line at the bottom of the help:

```
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management.
```

`apt` and the others are more user friendly than `dpkg` is, so they have the ability to read through the unconfigured that is left over from trying to install a `.deb` package that was downloaded from the internet and not from a repository.  Basically when you see `dependency problems - leaving unconfigured` means that it has left a "log" of the dependencies that need to be installed.  So, when you run the `sudo apt -f install` or `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
   man apt-get:

   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
       This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
       to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
       specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
       is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
       system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
       so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
       using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
       Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

it sends a command for `apt-get` to read that "log" of a broken installation (if exists), download and install the dependencies if they are available.

You can skip this step by actually going into the folder that you downloaded the `.deb` file into and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ./discord-0.0.14.deb
```

that will now tell `apt-get` to install the `.deb` package and download all dependencies if available for the package being installed.

I hope this helps!